# How do I use INSERT INTO by comparing ID and using WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

**Table1**

```
ID
Position
Other
Other
Name
Description
```

**Table2**

```
ID
Name
Description
LN
Other
```

I want to transfer all values from `Table2` into `Table1` where `Table1.ID = Table2.ID` and `Table2.LN = 'en'`

The following query gives an error. What is the correct way to formulate the query?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(Name, Description)
    SELECT  
        Name, Description 
    FROM
        dbo.Table2
    WHERE
        Table2.ID = Table1.ID 
        AND Table2.LN = 'en'
```

Comment: @Nov.....do you have a question for us?

Comment: An insert doesn't make any sense if the id's are in both tables do you mean to do an update?

Comment: the multi part identifier "Table1.ID" could not be bound

Comment: i used Table2 to check name depend of LN (en, fr), but since i go only en, i dont need Table2. I want to copy all en names into Table1

Answer (score 6):

```
Update table1
set table1.name = table2.name,
    table1.description = table2.description
from
table1  inner join
table2  on table1.id = table2.id
where table2.ln = 'en'
```

Comment: This `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ... INNER JOIN` syntax is pretty cool! It will come in handy. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You shoul use UPDATE not INSERT

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to be doing an Update instead of an INSERT sine you are mapping to ID's that already exist in Table1

[This shows how to create a Procedure to update multiple columns](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/b9c271f8-11c4-433c-917a-8987216f2ed4/)

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you want.  It is a minor variant on what you wrote, just including Table1 in the from clause:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(Name,Description)
    SELECT Name, Description
    FROM dbo.Table2 join
         Table1
         on Table2.id = Table1.id
    WHERE Table2.LN = 'en'
```

To me, this data layout looks a bit strange, because it inserts duplicates of "id" into Table1.  However, this does answer your question.